# Why does HttpResponseMessage not show its content?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, httpresponse

Hello i am trying to send a `Json` object using the `HttpResponseMessage` .
Even though while debugging the data looks like it was inserted in the `Content` section (`104` bytes present) when using `Postman` when retrieveing the json , in the `Content` section there is no data,just a header.

**JsonResponse**

```json
{
    "version": {
        "major": 1,
        "minor": 1,
        "build": -1,
        "revision": -1,
        "majorRevision": -1,
        "minorRevision": -1
    },
    "content": {
        "headers": [
            {
                "key": "Content-Type",
                "value": [
                    "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
                ]
            } ////why no data ??
        ]
    },
    "statusCode": 200,
    "reasonPhrase": "OK",
    "headers": [],
    "requestMessage": null,
    "isSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

As you can see there is no content.I am reusing the same code as in an earlier application and i did not get this problem.Why is the content empty?

**Code**

```
private static List<User> users = new List<User> {
    new User{ Id = 0, Age = 0, Name = "Failed"},
    new User{ Id = 12, Age = 33, Name = "Daniel"},
    new User{ Id = 13, Age = 33, Name = "Marian"},
};


[HttpGet]
[Route("/api/getusers")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetUsers() {
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(users);
    return new HttpResponseMessage {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content = new StringContent(str, Encoding.UTF8)
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET Core does not have built-in support for returning `HttpResponseMessage`. If you want to return JSON, you can use `IActionResult` and let ASP.NET Core handle the serialisation for you. Here's an updated example:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers() {
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return Json(users);
}
```

There are more options here, for situations where you want to allow [content-negotiation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.1), for example. Here's a version that supports content-negotiation using [`OkObjectResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.okobjectresult?view=aspnetcore-2.1):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers() {
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return Ok(users);
}
```

You can even just return `users` itself if you prefer:

```
public async Task<List<User>> GetUsers() {
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return users;
}
```

That should be enough to get you started - the official documentation explains things further: [Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: I wanted to return a `StatusCode` too.So i will need to create a wrapper around my object and the `StatusCode`.

Comment: If you mean a HTTP `StatusCode`, the approach I've shown will set it to 200 automatically. If you mean a custom `StatusCode` that's not HTTP-based, you will want to create your own wrapper class rather than using `HttpResponseMessage`. If that's the case, let me know and I'll provide an updated example.

Comment: No your solution is fine..i didn't understand that it included the status code.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian did you resolve this issue ? Are you able to see the content in the POSTMAN ?